# Perfect squares and modularly congruency in mod 5

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There is not any perfect square $k$ such that $k  \equiv 3\ (\textrm{mod}\ 5)$? Why? How can I prove it?

Comment: $\begin{eqnarray}{\rm mod}\ 5\!:\ &&\ \ x\equiv  0,\pm1,\pm2\\ \Rightarrow &&x^2\equiv 0,\ \ \  1,\,{-}1\not\equiv 2\end{eqnarray}\quad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at the residue classes mod 5: $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Now square them and reduce mod 5:

> $$\begin{pmatrix} x & | &x^2 \\- & - & - \\ 0 & | & 0 \\ 1 & | & 1 \\ 2 & | & 4 \\ 3 & | & 9(\equiv 4) \\4 & | &  16(\equiv 1)\end{pmatrix}$$

None of them are 3.

---

The lemma you need for this is:

**Lemma.** If $a\equiv b\mod n$ then $a^2\equiv b^2\mod n$.

*Proof.* Write $a=nk+r,\, b=nj+r$ then

> $$a^2=n(nk^2+2kr)+r^2=nk'+r^2,\; b^2=n(nj^2+2jr)+r^2=nj'+r^2.$$

Hence $n|(a^2-b^2)$, proving the lemma.

Comment: Very good. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @bigli No problem, glad to help. Remember to accept the answer if you consider the question closed so that people know you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the 5 cases:

If $n \equiv 0 \pmod{5} \Rightarrow n^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$

If $n \equiv 1 \pmod{5} \Rightarrow n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$

If $n \equiv 2 \pmod{5} \Rightarrow n^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$

If $n \equiv 3 \pmod{5} \Rightarrow n^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$

If $n \equiv 4 \pmod{5} \Rightarrow n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$

Comment: You can look into a generalized version of this problem. We say that $k$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod{p}$ if there is an integer $n$ such that $n^2 \equiv k \pmod{p}$.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue

Answer (score 1):

$$a\equiv0,\pm1,\pm2\pmod5\implies a^2\equiv0,1,4$$

But $\displaystyle3\not\equiv0,1,4\pmod5$