# Quadratic Modular Arithmetic

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

I want to prove that
$$ w^2 \equiv 2 \quad (\bmod{5})$$
has no solutions in integers.

What I tried:
$$ w^2 \equiv 2 \quad (\bmod{5})$$
$$ \Rightarrow w^2 =  2 + 5k,  \quad k \in \mathbb{Z} $$

Now, I don't know what to do, so I considered $x^2 = 2+ 5y$ over $\mathbb{R}$.
 We can solve this to see if the solutions are integers.

If it has no solutions in integers, can I then say that this implies that $ w^2 \equiv 2 \; (\bmod{5})$ has no solutions?
Is there a different approach to this problem?

Comment: Please show what quadratic equation that you are solving. if it is $x^2-5y-2=0$ and you are treating $x$ and $y$ as the same variable it is wrong. If its $x^2+0x-(5y+2)=0$ you don't need the quadratic formula.

Comment: Cf. this [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870314/perfect-squares-and-modularly-congruency-in-mod-5) with $3$ instead of $2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of modular arithmetic is reduction of the integers to finite sets. Thus you only have to account for a limited number of cases. In this problem, 0^2 = 0, 1^2 = 1, 2^2 = 4, 3^2 = 4, 4^2 = 1 in Z/5Z, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Modulo $5$, $x\equiv0, \pm1, $ or $\pm 2$.

What is $x^2 $ in each case?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how you finished the proof it can't be verified.

This should prove it though:

All multiples of $5$ end with the digit $5$ or $0$ in decimal base.
$$5+2=7$$
$$w^2\ne7+10n$$
$$w^2\ne2+10n$$
because no perfect squares end in $7$ or $2$ in decimal base.